# Runtime spike when memory usage exceeds specific value

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm learning CUDA and currently I am implementing the multiplication of two matrices. I'm testing with matrix dimneions of power of two, e.g. 1024, 2048, 4096 and so on.

Up until 8192 x 8192, the runtime increases by around factor 5-7, but then something strange happens: The calculation of 16384 x 16384 takes around factor 20 more time than the multiplicaton of 8192 x 8192. From that point on, the higher dimensions are slower at the known factor of 5-7, which would match what I observed from 1024^2 to 8192^2.

I'm struggling to find a suitable explanation for this spike in runtime. My first guess was that at some point the three matrices (two factors and one result matrix) don't fit into the L3 cache anymore (128 MB at my machine); but then I should get the spike earlier, between 2048 and 4096 (if I do the math right). VRAM shouldn't be an issue as well (24 GB).

My code:

```py
@cuda.jit
def parallel_matrix_multiplication(matrix1, matrix2, resMatrix, n):
    thread = cuda.threadIdx.x + cuda.blockIdx.x * cuda.blockDim.x

    if thread < n * n:
        col = thread // n
        row = thread % n 
        row_sum = 0

        for i in range(n):
            row_sum += matrix1[col][i] * matrix2[i][row]

        resMatrix[col][row] = row_sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 16384
    threads_per_block = 32
    blocks_per_grid = N * N // threads_per_block

    matrix1, matrix2 = fill_matrix()
    result_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(N, N))

    print(f"Measuring time for N = {N} and threads_per_block = {threads_per_block}")
    start_event = cuda.event()
    end_event = cuda.event()
    start_event.record()
    
    parallel_matrix_multiplication[blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block](matrix1, matrix2, result_matrix, N)

    end_event.record()
    end_event.synchronize()

    execution_time = cuda.event_elapsed_time(start_event, end_event)

    print(f"Execution time: {execution_time} ms")
```

Running on RTX 4090.

Comment: Thank you. First of all, you use 64-bit FP numbers while you GPU is clearly not designed for this. Computing 64-bit FP numbers is *64 times slower* than 32-bit ones on your GPU. This is so slow that most CPUs (at the same price) should be actually faster than your GPU. To compute 64-bit FP numbers efficiently, you need a server-size GPU which is far more expensive (e.g. 10x) than your client-side GPU (which is already expensive).

Comment: My guess is that the effect comes from the big stride of `matrix2[i][row]`. Lines are so big that it can cause *cache trashing* (especially since the matrix size is a power-of-two), and also slower VRAM accesses (like DRAM). Padding should fix cache trashing. For VRAM accesses, you need to use blocking and a better layout (blocking or Z-order curves).

Comment: Oh and since the matrices are also stored on the CPU, you need to check the CPU memory is not too high. If there is not enough memory on the CPU, then it will cause memory swapping which is very very expensive. I advise you to transfer data manually to the GPU so to measure the time of the kernel independently of data transfert (which are currently implicit)

Comment: By the way, note that this kind of computation should already be implemented in CuBLAS.

Comment: Thank you for your comments so far. I actually fill the matrices with integers, which I expected to be 4 bytes long as in C++. In fact, I built an implementation in C++-CUDA which works the same way (passes over the matrices as a whole, same layout etc.), but hasn't this runtime spike, but the overall runtime is worse than in Python. The C++ version has a factor of 7 between 8192 and 16384, like expected. Since both implementations run on the same hardware, I get a feeling that Python does something in another way than C++.

Comment: Just saw that I fill the result array with float64 zeros, didn't see that default argument.

Comment: The `dtype` is not specified so it is 64-bit FP number (`np.float64`) by default. This is critical to specify it for sake of performance (and to avoid weird effects sometimes too). `np.zeros(shape=(N, N)).dtype` is `np.float64` for example (the type of the resulting matrix). Numba also use 64-bit integers by default. You need to manually specify the type for them (which is cumbersome but mandatory for performance AFAIK). If the C++ version operate on `float` then this is 32-bit ones. Thus, if the effect is related to the size of the matrix, then it may appear only on 32768² matrices.

Comment: Besides Numba transfer the matrices to/from the GPU automatically but this automatic process is generally inefficient. AFAIK, the matrices are transferred back even when they are only read (didn't check though). This is why a manual transfer is often better (you can also use streams so to overlap communications with computations).

Comment: For example, in Numba, when you do `row_sum = 0`, Numba uses a 64-bit integer (slower than 32-bit on your GPU). If it see that FP numbers are written to `row_sum`, then it unify the type and changes it to 64-bit FP numbers which are slow. Such behaviour is bad for performance though it has the benefit to be convenient for users who to not care much about that (as opposed to Cython where native types are always manually specified).